# Sign In With Google: Get Refresh Token from the returned Id Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

With the new "[Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)" Google has started returning id_token as a response and deprecated the "[grantOfflineAccess](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration?hl=en#object_migration_reference_for_user_sign-in)" function which was being used to get the offline token for the user.

How do I get an offline token from the Id token?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to I decided to go with the old sign-in library.

Comment: A solution that worked for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69746036/380316